# Selenium - CSS Selectors : How to find out which color is a selector in a long list of items, for each item?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, element

In the page I'm working on - I have a list of items (#54), for each item I have several parameters such as : Name, Price change, other parameters & Clock, that shows red or green. Please look into the screenshot

**The Mission : To know for each item/row what color is its clock**

I made a list of items names and I can print its name with a dedicated selector for the name - The Easy Part is Done!

[image]

**Additional info**

1. Each clock with each color has a unique id lets say:
   Green : class='green',
   Red : class='red'
2. Each item row has a unique css selector for the whole row, the clock selector is a child inside the row's css selector

So, for each item I would like to know whether its clock is red or green. So I tried the follow solutions:

1)To insert the clocks into a second list, but here comes the problem: If I Insert the clock into a list, I can do it only but a 'Contains' CSS selector identifier [class* = xxx], and then the program cannot distinguish which is red and which is green

2)I have a CSS selector for a whole row, I tried to take it into a list, and then somehow to find : 'Whole row Css > Clock CSS'. That did not work as well.

Can you give me any idea how to find for each item what the color of the clock is?

```
public static void WatchlistInstrumentsList(WebDriver driver, boolean finalstatus ,ExtentTest logger,int SocketChangeCounter) throws InterruptedException
{


    int size = 2;

    for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++) {
        //for (int j=1 ; j<sizex ; j=j+2)
        //{

        // Create a list of instruments
        List <WebElement> listName;
        List <WebElement> rowsData;


        // The selector of instrument's name
        listName= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id='tbody_overview_3032754']>[id^='sort_']>[data-column-name='name']>[target='_blank']"));
        // The selector of a whole row (all datat inside)
        rowsData= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id='tbody_overview_3032754']>[id^='sort_']")); 




        // ** Works on Browser search [id='tbody_overview_3032754']>[id^='sort_']>[data-column-name='name']>[target='_blank'] **//

        size = listName.size();




        try {
        String name = listName.get(i).getText(); // instrument's name taken from list
        System.out.println("Instrument's name:" +name +" , Instrument's counter:" +i);
        finalstatus = true;

        // ***HOW TO FIND THE CLOCK COLOR ****** ///

        }


        //TestClockOfInstrument.runTestClockWatchlist(driver, finalstatus, logger, i, SocketChangeCounter);

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the website link to the screenshot?

Comment: link: https://www.investing.com/portfolio/?portfolioID=NTNiMWAwMG5kMmlhNG4%3D

Sign-In via email : dimainvesting@gmail.com || password: de123456

Comment: Tnx, i will try some different stuff

Comment: Amazing bro I'm really thankful

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I have added my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.get("https://www.investing.com/portfolio/?portfolioID=NTNiMWAwMG5kMmlhNG4%3D");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='PromoteSignUpPopUp']//div[@class='right']/i[@class='popupCloseIcon']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginFormUser_email")).sendKeys("dimainvesting@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm_password")).sendKeys("de123456");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signup']/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navMenu']/ul/li[9]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[contains(@class,'myPortfolioTbl')]//tr/td[20]/span"));
    for (int i =0 ; i< elementList.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println(elementList.get(i).getAttribute("class"));
    }
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My Friend, you gave the a perfect solution that I found a few hours ago.

1) I collected all elements via css selector using a Common element value : [class*='xxx'], inserted then into a list

2) Now all clock elements are recognized as the same one by the list, because I collected them via common css value

3) I used : elementList.get(i).getAttribute("class")), to get their full attribute value and now I can distinguish between : Red & Green

Sudha Velan - Thank you for taking your time to help, very appreciated